# Calculating position of object based on number of objects

Tags: math, lua

I have a simple question but am having a hard time coming up with an elegant solution.

Let's say that my app displays a deck of cards.  Each time I draw a card, I want to display it in the center of the screen.   When I draw a new card, I want to display that card next to the previous one and both be centered.

So more specifically if my code had the following variables and tables

N = total cards played.  Assume N is between 1 and 10.

W = width to separate each card in pixels. For example 30px

C = width of screen / 2 ( center x value for the screen )

P = {}  -- which denotes the position of the card and it's new X value.     P[1] will be the x value for the first card played.

I want a formula so I can run a loop and calculate the new X value for each card.

Here is my expected output

N = 1, P[1] = C.  If there is only 1 card, then the x value of that card will be the center

N = 2, P[1] = C - W/2, P[2] = C + W/2

N = 3, P[1] = C - W, P[2] = C, P[3] = C + W

N = 4, P[1] = C - 3/2 * W, P[2] = C - 1/2 * W, P[3] = C + 1/2 * W, P[4] = C + 3/2 * W

So I need a loop which programatically calculates this for me.  Not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula should do the trick:

```
P[k] = C + W * (k - 1 - (N - 1) / 2)
```

where `k = 1,2,...,N` is the number of the card.

The various cases are:

```
N = 1  => P[k] = C + W * (k - 1)  
       => P[1] = C

N = 2  => P[k] = C + W * (k - 1 - 1/2)  
       => P[1] = C - W/2,  P[2] = C + W/2

N = 3  => P[k] = C + W * (k - 1 - 1)  
       => P[1] = C - W,  P[2] = C,   P[3] = C + W

N = 4  => P[k] = C + W * (k - 1 - 3/2)  
       => P[1] = C - 3W/2,  P[2] = C - W/2,   P[3] = C + W/2,   P[4] = C + 3W/2

...
```

You can wrap the formula in a nifty function, as in the following test program, which produces more or less the same scheme above:

```
local C = 10
local W = 20


local function CardPosition( k, N )
    return C + W * (k - 1 - (N - 1) / 2)
end

for N = 1, 5 do
    io.write( "N = ", N, " => P[k] = ", 
        C, " + ", W, " * (k - 1 - ", N - 1, "/2) \n" )
    io.write "      => "
    for k = 1, N do
        io.write( "P[", k,"] = ", CardPosition(k, N), ",  " )
    end
    io.write "\n\n"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily spot that P[1] = C - (N-1)/2 * W in the cases you described. This is generally true, because the total width increases linearly with the number of cards.
Other cards' positions can be computed with the help of the expression: P[x] = P[x-1] + W.